# In Vue, how to get the content of a textarea?

Tags: vue.js

I want to keep the value of a variable identical with the content of a textarea.

I don't want to use `v-bind` or `v-model`, because I have already bound the textarea with another value.

This is a notebook app, and the textarea is used to display the content of a note, so it has been bound using `v-bind` with a `note` object, like

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="3" v-bind:value="note"></textarea>
```

Now, I want to add the "edit note" functionality. So when the content of the textarea changes, I want to store its value into a variable, and when the "submit" button is clicked, I pass the value of the variable, which contains the new content of the note, to backend to update the note.

My question is, how to store the textarea's content into the variable after each time the content changes?

I think I cannot use `v-model` because this way the note will be changed right after the content of the textarea is modified (though not sent to backend), but this is not what I want. What I want is the note to be changed ***only after*** the "submit" button is clicked. Thus, I cannot use `v-model`

Should I use `v-on:change`? If so, how to get the content of the textarea?

Like,

```html
<textarea v-on:change="updateTheVariable(I need to get the content of the textarea here)"> ... </textarea>
```

```js
methods: {
    updateTheVariable(content of the textarea) {
        this.variable = content of the textarea
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this is exactly what `v-model` does... adds an event listener for the `input` event and updates the bound value with the text.

Comment: @Phil, I bound variable_1 with the textarea so it sends content to the textarea, but now I need to make the textarea update variable_2.

Comment: Perhaps `variable_2` should be a computed property based on `variable_1`.

Comment: @Phil you already helped me! Your deleted answer, "@input="$event.target.value", is exactly what I need. Thanks. You can post you answer again and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: No, because I do not understand what you're trying to do and believe there's a better way

Comment: @Phil I have added more description. Hopefully it is clear enough now. If so, please post your deleted answer and I will accept it.

Comment: _"it has been bound using v-bind with a note object"_  this doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Could you please update it and also explain why you cannot just use `v-model="note"`

Comment: @Phil I added a 2nd last paragraph, hope it is clear this time...

Comment: What's wrong with changing `note`? It's just a variable in JS. Where does `note` come from; is it a `data` property or a `prop`. If the former, when does it get a value assigned?

Comment: Yeah, it is only about frontend, but the changed note will be displayed, without the user clicking "submit". It is not a very good experience. I think if the user doesn't click "submit" then all changes made in the textarea should be abandoned instead of being displayed on the screen. ```note``` is a ```data``` property obtained from backend

Comment: @Phil ```note``` is assigned in ```created()```

Comment: You can use the ref and get value of target which would be better way. Access the value using $ref.ref_name.value inside method updatevariable()

Comment: @powerseed my answer has been un-deleted but it's quite different now

Comment: @DharmikRaval I just read an artical about ```$ref``` after reading your instruction, since I didn't know it before that. However, ```$ref```doesn't work for me because the display of the textarea is determined by ```v-if```. It is not displayed by default, so ```$ref``` cannot find it. Hopefully if I tried it correctly. Thank you all the same!

Comment: I tried use v-model in this case and got "Internal server error: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.
Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead." as I'm using Typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil indicated in a deleted post, the right way to do it is

```
<textarea @input="updateTheVariable($event.target.value)"></textarea>
.
.
.
methods:{
    updateTheVariable(value){
         this.variable = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this thing only shows up when you click some kind of *edit* button which is why you don't want to alter `note` so try something like this instead

```html
<button type="button" v-if="!editMode" @click="editNote">Edit</button>
<form v-if="editMode" @submit="handleSubmit">
  <fieldset :disabled="saving">
    <textarea v-model="editingNote"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    note: 'whatever', // maybe it's a prop, maybe assigned later, doesn't matter
    editMode: false,
    editingNote: null, // this will be used to bind the edited value
    saving: false
  }),
  methods: {
    editNote () {
      this.editingNote = this.note
      this.editMode = true
      this.saving = false
    },
    async handleSubmit () {
      this.saving = true // disables form inputs and buttons

      await axios.post('/notes/update', { note: this.editingNote}) // just an example

      this.note = this.editingNote // or maybe use data from the response ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
      // or if it's a prop, this.$emit('updated', this.editingNote)
      this.editMode = false
    }
  }
}
```